# What does it mean to design something by using "first principles"?

Tags: product-engineering

A fan of Elon musk but have hard time understanding his engineering approach when he says use "first principles". Could anyone elaborate on that ?

When we got a problem at hand what is the first principle way to solve the problem ?

Reference
www.youtube.com/watch?v=NV3sBlRgzTI

Comment: Hi Rıfat Erdem Sahin, welcome to Engineering SE. As it stands this question is more suited to an open-ended discussion forum than to our focused style of Q&A. If you can elaborate on some particular aspect of the explanation in the video that you find difficult to understand, that could help to bring this in scope.